# Acceder a nodo padre de tabla dinamica en xslt

Tags: xml, xsl, xslt

tengo la siguiente estructura xml:

```
<pago10:Pagos Version="1.0">
      <pago10:Pago FechaPago="2017-09-09T12:00:00" FormaDePagoP="03" MonedaP="MXN" Monto="14000.00" NumOperacion="012180004457813372" RfcEmisorCtaOrd="BBA830831LJ2" NomBancoOrdExt="Banco patito" CtaOrdenante="0445781337" RfcEmisorCtaBen="BMN930209927" CtaBeneficiario="0560877">
        <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="8A2D55A5-XXXX-4B28-AC8C-6E72EFBCFA61" Serie="A" Folio="1132" MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PUE" ImpSaldoAnt="14000" ImpPagado="14000" ImpSaldoInsoluto="0" />
      </pago10:Pago>
      <pago10:Pago FechaPago="2017-09-09T12:00:00" FormaDePagoP="04" MonedaP="MXN" Monto="14000.00" NumOperacion="012180004457813372" RfcEmisorCtaOrd="BBA830831LJ2" NomBancoOrdExt="Banco patito" CtaOrdenante="0445781337" RfcEmisorCtaBen="BMN930209927" CtaBeneficiario="0560877">
        <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="8A2D55A5-XXXX-4B28-AC8C-6E72EFBCFA62" Serie="A" Folio="1132" MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PUE" ImpSaldoAnt="14000" ImpPagado="14000" ImpSaldoInsoluto="0" />
        <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="8A2D55A5-XXXX-4B28-AC8C-6E72EFBCFA63" Serie="A" Folio="1132" MonedaDR="MXN" MetodoDePagoDR="PUE" ImpSaldoAnt="14000" ImpPagado="14000" ImpSaldoInsoluto="0" />
      </pago10:Pago>
</pago10:Pagos>
```

y pinto una tabla con todos los tags de `DoctoRelacionado`:

```
IdDocumento*** Serie *** Folio ** etc

8A........FA61 ** A ** 1123 ** ...

8A........FA62 ** A **  1132 ** ...

8A........FA63 ** A **  1132 ** ...
```

Los asteriscos serían como la división de columnas.
El problema es que necesito agregar una columna con un atributo del nodo `pago` que es padre de `DoctoRelacionado`, en especifico con `FormaDePagoP` de tal forma que la tabla quede así:

```
IdDocumento*** Serie *** Folio ** FormaDePagoP

8A........FA61 ** A ** 1123 ** 03

8A........FA62 ** A **  1132 ** 04

8A........FA63 ** A **  1132 ** 04
```

¿Como podría hacer esto con `xpath` o con `xslt`? Estoy restringido a `xslt 1.0`. y puedo apoyarme de `Altova stylevision`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya logre resolverlo, lo respondo por si a alguien le sirve, al final hice una tabla de una columna para el nodo `pago10:Pago` y dentro de esa celda hice la otra tabla `pago10:DoctoRelacionado`, de esta forma pude extraer `FormaDePagoP` y colocarlo como subtitulo de la tabla y ya no como columna. Por cada valor diferente de `FormaDePagoP` aparecera una tabla con su valor correspondiente. La tabla de una celda de `pago10:Pago` le quite bordes y fondo para que no se note que existe.
Esta es la idea principal del código (no coloque todas las columnas):

```
<table border="0">
    <tbody>
        <xsl:for-each select="pago10:Pagos">
            <xsl:for-each select="pago10:Pago">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table style="font-size:8px; " border="1">
                            <thead>
                                <tr style="height:0.13in; line-height:normal; ">
                                    <th colspan="8" style="background-color:#0071bb; font-size:6px; width:1.80in; ">
                                        <br/>
                                        <span style="font-size:10px; vertical-align:middle; ">
                                            <xsl:text>Forma de pago: </xsl:text>
                                        </span>
                                        <xsl:for-each select="@FormaDePagoP">
                                            <span style="font-size:10px; ">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
                                            </span>
                                        </xsl:for-each>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="background-color:#0071bb; height:0.13in; ">
                                    <th style="width:1.80in; ">
                                        Columna 1
                                    </th>
                                    <th style="width:0.60in; ">
                                        Columna 2
                                    </th>
                                    ...
                                    <th style="width:0.60in; ">
                                        Columna n
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <xsl:for-each select="pago10:DoctoRelacionado">
                                    <tr align="center">
                                        <td style="width:1.80in; ">
                                            <xsl:for-each select="@IdDocumento">
                                                <span>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
                                                </span>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width:0.60in; ">
                                            <xsl:for-each select="@Serie">
                                                <span>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
                                                </span>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                            <span>
                                                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                                            </span>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="@Folio">
                                                <span>
                                                    <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
                                                </span>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </td>
                                        ...
                                    </tr>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <br/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]